why I can not get metadata for some concrete tokens?
Using this code:
import { Connection, PublicKey } from '@solana/web3.js';
// strong text@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata": "^2.13.0"
import { Metaplex } from '@metaplex-foundation/js';

const RPC_URL:string = "https://broken-summer-shape.solana-mainnet.quiknode.pro/**[YOUR_KEY]**/";
const MINT_ADDR:string = "4sp2EUDrQf46rZun6sYAWzjrXwUpx2T3njuoKmV766RJ"; //HAMI

(async()=>{

    let connection:Connection = new Connection(RPC_URL);
    const metaplex = new Metaplex(connection);

    try{
        const nftMetadata = await metaplex.nfts().findByMint({ mintAddress: new PublicKey(MINT_ADDR) });
        console.log(JSON.stringify(nftMetadata));
    }catch(e){
        console.log((e as Error).message);
    }
})();

I can get metadata (o empty data) for tokens account, for example:
const MINT_ADDR:string = "5DPKMXmf9WK1C6N1MoJLWjYApiP4KR8zNf1oofevGEub"; // SPL TOKEN
const MINT_ADDR:String = "C1w2uRGBAA8FPoovchBVAb1uuVEqs6g77TCHe2bbJG8G"; // Ceramonio

But I can NOT get answer for this token even when it has metadata:
const MINT_ADDR:String = "C1w5UgaszaJxAstFtaPSXej6nwk8EcSQdc5dkxm6ruVr"; // Javia Brown-Turner

Any idea?

you are using the deprecated API for the Metaplex SDK.
Please switch to UMI and the metadata package
import { createUmi } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults";
import { fetchDigitalAsset } from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata'
import { dasApi } from "@metaplex-foundation/digital-asset-standard-api";

const umi = createUmi(clusterApiUrl("devnet"));
umi.use(keypairIdentity(keypair)).use(mplTokenMetadata()).use(dasApi());

const MINT_ADDR:String = "C1w2uRGBAA8FPoovchBVAb1uuVEqs6g77TCHe2bbJG8G"; // Ceramonio

const fetchAsset = async () => {
    const asset = await (await fetchDigitalAsset(umi, publicKey(MINT_ADDR)));
    console.log("asset \n", asset);
}

Alternatively, you could use the DAS API to fetch the token details
const fetchAsset = async () => {
    const asset = await umi.rpc.getAsset(publicKey(collectible));
    console.log("asset \n", asset);
}

REF -> https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/fetch

Did you test your code?, I miss publicKey, keypairIdentity, keypair...

I post below your code with those problems solved. Thanks a lot.

Based on Jimii answer but solving some code problems:
import { createUmi } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults"; // ^0.9.1
import { fetchDigitalAsset, mplTokenMetadata } from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata'; // ^3.2.1
import { clusterApiUrl, PublicKey } from '@solana/web3.js'; // ^1.91.7
import { publicKey, PublicKeyInput } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi"; // ^0.9.1

const umi = createUmi(clusterApiUrl('mainnet-beta')).use(mplTokenMetadata());
const MINT_ADDR:PublicKeyInput<string> = "C1w2uRGBAA8FPoovchBVAb1uuVEqs6g77TCHe2bbJG8G"; // Ceramonio

const fetchAsset = async () => {
    const asset = await fetchDigitalAsset(umi, publicKey(MINT_ADDR));
    console.log("asset \n", asset);
}

fetchAsset();

